# Oracle: Am I on a RAC?

Tags: oracle, rac

What query can I perform to determine if I am running on a RAC system?  If I'm on a RAC, I need to query from GV$* rather than V$*.

Comment: You can always use the gv$* views, they work with single instances, too. This removes the hassle to check if you are on RAC or not

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can check the value of the `CLUSTER_DATABASE` parameter:

```
SQL> select name, value from v$parameter where name = 'cluster_database';

NAME                  VALUE
--------------------- ---------------------
cluster_database      TRUE
```

According to the [Oracle Database Reference](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E18283_01/server.112/e17110/initparams026.htm):

> `CLUSTER_DATABASE` is an Oracle RAC parameter that specifies whether or not Oracle RAC is enabled.

If your account does not have access to data dictionary views like `V$PARAMETER`, you can use the below PL/SQL block to detect if your database is clustered:

```
begin
  if dbms_utility.is_cluster_database then
    dbms_output.put_line('True');
  else
    dbms_output.put_line('False');
  end if;
end;
/
```